# Reportlab - ListFlowable, Generate Listitem from given list of strings

Tags: python, reportlab

This is my first StackOverflow post so I would like to apologize if I have made any markup mistakes or anything similar.

This is the current project I am working on:
I am developing a Django web application that's responsible for generating audit reports based on dynamic input by the user. The user will have the option to refer a variation of files.

The current issue I am facing is the following:

I would like to generate a bulletlist of static elements given in a list.
This is the code I have so far.

```
def generateList(list_of_bullets):
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    t1 = ListFlowable([
         for element in list_of_bullets:
             ListItem(Paragraph(element, styles['Normal']), bulletColor=CMYKColor(0.81,0.45,0.53,0.23), value='circle')
   )], bulletType='bullet', start='circle')
   story.append(t1)
```

PyCharm reports a Expression expected on ListFlowable([ <-

the code below works just fine

```
def get_bullet_list():
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    t1 = ListFlowable([ListItem(Paragraph("Sample Text", styles['Normal']), bulletColor=CMYKColor(0.81, 0.45, 0.53, 0.23), value='circle')], bulletType='bullet', start='circle')
```

So my question is: Is there any way I can dynamically append ListItems to a ListFlowable?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do this dynamically thanks to a kind user on #python @ irc.freenode.org.

The following code is tested and works.

```
def makeBulletList(list):
    styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
    style=styles['Normal']
    table=ListFlowable([ListItem(Paragraph(x, style), leftIndent=35, bulletColor='black', value='circle') for x in list], bulletType='bullet')
    return table
```